# How do mail apps get access to your mailbox without being added as a authorized application in the azure ad?

Tags: c#, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

How do third party mailapps like samsung email and many others get access to exchange data without being registred as a application in the azure ad?

Every guide about exchange authentification (OAuth) i found online had the requirement to register your application in the azure active directory before it can be used to read mails etc. But if that's the case, how do widespreaded mailapps like samsung deal with this problem? They are never listed as an registerted application, yet they have full access on your mails, calendar etc. In real-time too.

I try to solve this with an app that is written in c# using the .net framework. I dont know if that is already a problem in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

> How do third party mailapps like samsung email and many others get
> access to exchange data without being registered as a application in
> the azure ad?

[image]

Samsung have their own Azure Application registration that must be consented to  its generally done once by the tenant admin.

There is a good reason for the consent framework to allow both control of what applications can access data but also to allow for the correct auditing of the access. If you want to know what App registration a particular mail client is using just look at the Azure Signin logs. Another recent case was around this Apple's mail app see https://practical365.com/microsoft-auto-update-apple-mail-app-profiles/

Comment: Ok now i am confused even more. We have android and iphone user in our company who have their mailbox connected to either the samsung or apple mail-app. They can read and write e-mails without any problems. But if I log into our azure active directory i dont see a single row that refers to one of them.. there are just 2 for backup purposes and the one i created for testing and thats it?

Comment: When i connected my own mail to the samsung app i even got asked for the permissions but there are still no entries in our azure ad. I can write and read mails without problems.

Comment: Are you looking at App registration or Enterprise Applications it will only appear under Enterprise Applications once its been consented to, if you remove all the filters in EA in the portal you can see all the wellknown/pre approved apps from Microsoft (over 300)